# In QueryDsl - Is it possible to Join against a sql function returning a table

Tags: querydsl

I have a sql function which returns a table. Something like below where split_return_id_table is a sql function which accepts a string of ids comma seperated and converts to a table with id column

```
select us.* from user us
    inner join split_return_id_table('1,2,3',',') id_list on ( id_list.id = us.id)
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar in queryDsl

Comment: Seems like not as mentioned in comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75284680/how-to-join-with-array-in-querydsl/75288963