# How to join with array in querydsl

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

I a trying to write below query in querydsl

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users AS u
   JOIN unnest(ARRAY[2,2,1]) WITH ORDINALITY AS arr(elem, ord)
      ON u.id = arr.elem
ORDER BY arr.ord;
```

How can I join on array if ids

I tried registering unnest function too

```
public class Contributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("unnest",
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "array[?1]"));
    }
}
```

But this is also not working, I am getting `unexpected token: unnest`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that while PostgreSQL has support for native arrays and the unnest operator, JPA currently does not in its query language (JPQL) which Querydsl / Spring Boot have to use as an intermediary. So unfortunately, this is not supported.

Comment: I saw one can register functions eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70584908/how-to-join-on-unnest-columns-using-jpql  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686971/hibernate-postgresql-how-to-search-in-an-array-column but this is not working for me.

Comment: Yes, because even though you can register custom functions, it's not possible to use functions as join target or from clause.

Comment: ah I see. Thanks for this info. Wondering if it is possible to write native query for above using querydsl but use its dynamic projection to select columns at runtime